# Locked Stardew Valley question for more than 3 years now

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, locks

Just noticed that this Stardew Valley question has been locked since May 2016, apparently due to an edit war about its title: [Do I get any benefits from petting my chicken?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/260564/do-i-get-any-benefits-from-petting-my-chicken)

Since it's been more than 3 years and an edit war is unlikely to happen again, it should probably be unlocked now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, definitely. Most locks should be temporary, especially in the case of edit wars. I have removed the lock, hopefully the question won't have to be locked again.

As a side note, a flag on the question would've been fine too, rather than a meta post. (unless locked posts can't be flagged, but I'm not aware of that being the case)

Comment: I was thinking of flagging it too at first. But the 'locked' notification seems to recommend posting on meta: "You may discuss this on meta if you have concerns."

Comment: In this case, the edit war was pretty straightforward, it wasn't about anything worthy of particular discussion like the post's content, it was just about wording. This specific lock was a way for the moderators to say "Things are getting a little too heated up, let's cool down for a while". It's been 3 years since then, plenty of time for the lock to have served its purpose, so there's less need for a discussion about the post.

Comment: Alright. I found other questions with similar cases. I'll be flagging them.

Comment: @galacticninja If you see a questions been locked for content disputes or off-topic comments for more than a few weeks,  then chances are we just forgot to unlock it, so feel free to just flag it for moderator attention.